# Spyder how to delete folders from the "browse working directory" dropdown

Tags: spyder

I would like to remove several folder options from the browse working directory dropdown. I do not want to delete the folders themselves, I just want to unclutter the dropdown.

[image: Spyder Toolbar]

I have read through the Spyder docs from Debugger to Variable explorer and have seen no references to the dropdown menu. Google searches only turn up people asking to delete the actual folder, not cleaning up the dropdown menu so I suspect I am calling it the wrong name but I see no reference to it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the .spyder-py3 folder (for me this was in my user directory), open the workingdir file, delete the folders you no longer want to appear in the working directory dropdown, and then restart spyder! :)